# MySQL keeps crashing

Tags: database

Every couple of weeks or so, all the sites on my server (all running Craft) go down with the error message:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286 Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'
```

It seems unique to Craft and unique to this server. None of the sites are particularly busy. It's likely a server thing, I know, but has anyone run into this and got a fix?

Thanks,
Clive

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that InnoDB is installed and enabled for MySQL on this server, that error can also happen when InnoDB fails to start - for whatever reason. i.e. insufficient disk space, log file size, corrupt data, etc.

Check your MySQL log files for the underlying error.